# Resetting an object, and restarting a game

Tags: object, reset, 2d-games

In a game I made, I want to restart the game when the players presses a button.

I have an instance of a `Game` class, which is where most of the game happens.

I though that I could simply initialize it again, and it will be reset.

`Game game = new Game();` - When the program launches.
`game = new Game();` - When restarting the game.

But the game uses a lot of additional classes, such as `Tank` and `Missile`. Do I have to initialize all of them too, or is initializing the Game class, which will create new `Tank` objects and `Missile` objects (with the same reference names as the previous Game instance), enough?

In general, what would be the best way to reset a game or a level in a game?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To provide a function that resets everything that needs to be reseted? Creating a new instance of this possibly complex object seems redundant and a waste of resources.